# Redirect https://example to https://www.example.com Vhost

Tags: linux, apache, redirect

I am trying to implement a redirect which takes my site from https://example.com to https://www.example.com via redirect and not from the .htaccess file. Our site already redirects http requests to https://www.example.com. I posted what we have below.

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
ServerName www.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName www.example.com:443
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
SSL information here
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! How far along are you? (What happens if you try this now?) Have you configured your DNS so that the bare domain (`example.com`) points to your web server, or is that outside the bounds of what you're asking here?

Comment: Hi Jeff. Thanks for the response. - yes both example.com and www.example.com point to the web server. Everything works from http > https and  https://www.. The only issue is getting https://example.com to work with https://www.example.com. Hopefully this gives you more clarification.

Comment: Have you consulted the [documentation on canonical hostnames](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html#canonicalhost)?

Comment: "The only issue is getting `https://example.com` to work with `https://www.example.com`" - From the code you've included in your question, presumably `http://example.com` would also be an issue currently?

Comment: Nope that currently works as we have all http requests redirecting to https. Only issue is https://example.com not redirecting.

Comment: @MikeScott So how did you get on with ReynaldoAceve's answer?

Answer (score 0):

Adjust just HTTPS/443 virtual hosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName www.example.com:443
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
SSL information here
```